# Java Newbie : Are the two ways of function definition identical

Tags: java, function

If I create a function which returns an boolean value, I can't tell the difference between the following two ways:

**Way 1:**

```
public boolean isRight(){
      if(CONDITION){
          return true;
      }else{
          return false;
      }

}
```

**way 2:**

```
public boolean isRight(){
      if(CONDITION){
          return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

Can I say the above two ways of creating my function which returns an boolean value are equal/identical? Are there any differences logically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

sure. they are semantically equal.

even better, however:

```
public boolean isRight(){
      return CONDITION;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Neither one is more efficient than the other. The compiler can easily see that the two are identical, and in fact Suns/Oracles javac produces identical bytecode for the two methods.

Here is an IfTest class:

```
lass IfTest {

public boolean eq1(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;

    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    return true;
}


public boolean eq2(Object obj) {

    if (this == obj)
        return true;

    else if (obj == null)
        return false;

    else if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

}

I compiled it with javac and the disassembly is as follows:

```
public boolean eq1(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   if_acmpne   7
   5:   iconst_1
   6:   ireturn
   7:   aload_1
   8:   ifnonnull   13
   11:  iconst_0
   12:  ireturn
   13:  aload_0
   14:  invokevirtual   #2; //Method Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   17:  aload_1
   18:  invokevirtual   #2; //Method Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   21:  if_acmpeq   26
   24:  iconst_0
   25:  ireturn
   26:  iconst_1
   27:  ireturn
```

and

```
public boolean eq2(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   if_acmpne   7
   5:   iconst_1
   6:   ireturn
   7:   aload_1
   8:   ifnonnull   13
   11:  iconst_0
   12:  ireturn
   13:  aload_0
   14:  invokevirtual   #2; //Method Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   17:  aload_1
   18:  invokevirtual   #2; //Method Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   21:  if_acmpeq   26
   24:  iconst_0
   25:  ireturn
   26:  iconst_1
   27:  ireturn
```

That is, I would recommend using the first version (without the else). Some people may argue that it's cleaner with the else parts, but I would argue the opposite. Including the else indicates that the programmer didn't realize that it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are identical. This is because after the first `return` statement, `CONDITION` is guaranteed to be false.

Although this is actually a useless statement. Just use `CONDITION` instead of `isRight()`, because they are also always equivalent.

So, all of these are equivalent:

```
public boolean isRight() {
    if (CONDITION) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}
```

and

```
public boolean isRight() {
    if (CONDITION) { return true; }
    return false;
}
```

and

```
public boolean isRight() {
    return CONDITION;
}
```

and

```
CONDITION
```

They are... the same. `isRight()` just returns `CONDITION`, so you should just use `CONDITION` in place of `isRight()`.

Comment: The `CONDITION` can depend on some state in the class and therefor it is likely that `isRight()` cannot be changed to `CONDITION`.

Comment: If `isRight()` returns `CONDITION` then they are the same. Compare the last two examples.

Comment: `if (myObject.isRight()) { ... }` can probably not be replaced with `if (CONDITION) { ... }`. That's what I am saying. `CONDITION` is probably just a pseudo-code placeholder.

Comment: If `CONDITION` is a complex condition, than it is preferable to use a method to hide that and give it a useful name; it usually also makes it easier to test in separation, and it prevents errors if `CONDITION` occurs in more than one place (but by accident with minor variations).

Comment: I was assuming that `CONDITION` was a variable... and if it's not, just make one!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They are exactly the same.

Comment: In my opinion it is a valid answer for the question above.

Answer (score 0):

They are absolutely identical, but the second one is better to me, as you can quickly identify the default value returned. Some will say the first snippet is more readable, but it's as you prefer.